# Not able to execute apt-update in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, debian

I'm not able to run a simple Dockerimage with contents like:

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get update
```

I keep getting these error messages:

```
#0 20.18 Err:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#0 20.18   Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
#0 20.18 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#0 20.18   Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
#0 40.20 Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
#0 40.20   Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org'
```

I've tried a dozen of possible solutions mentioned on the internet like:

- add `{"dns": ["192.168.1.1", "8.8.8.8"]}` to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
- run `sudo systemctl restart docker.service`
- run `docker system prune`
- reboot my operating system (Arch Linux)
- tried different images, even an ubuntu one, but same issue

But none of them did the trick. Anyone who can possibly help me out?

**EDIT 1**:

I completely re-installed docker on my system, without any luck. Still no connection to the internet. At this moment, I've no idea what to do to fix this problem.

**EDIT 2**:
Results Philippe asked for.

```
$ docker run busybox ip a
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
19d511225f94: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:3614ca5eacf0a3a1bcc361c939202a974b4902b9334ff36eb29ffe9011aaad83
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: eth0@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and

```
$ docker run busybox ip r
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link  src 172.17.0.2
```

And just in case, my iptables:

```
$ sudo  iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Can you run `ping 8.8.8.8` in a container ?

Comment: From my host I can, but not from a docker container. I tried a docker image with ping installed https://hub.docker.com/r/willfarrell/ping, which didn't work.

Comment: Can you run `docker run busybox ip a` and `docker run busybox ip r` and paste results ?

Comment: @Philippe see EDIT 2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Seemed I had some nft rules set which were conflicting with the iptables. Just a simple command as flushing the nft ruleset, fixed the issue:

```
sudo nft flush ruleset
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly your local docker setup. Can you network from other containers?  If so, we need to look into `debian:buster`; if not it is likely your host / docker setting.

For what it is worth I have no issues here (using `testing` as I do not have `buster` locally):

```
$ docker run --rm -ti debian:testing apt update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing InRelease [130 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages [8535 kB]
Fetched 8665 kB in 2s (5011 kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
84 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
$
```

My host operating system in Ubuntu 22.04 but that should be immaterial.

Comment: So it seems my local setup. Your `docker run` command didn't work for me either and I'm not able to run ping on any container, because it isn't installed (just like curl, wget and such aren't installed). But one Dockerfile which used to work fine, doesn't work anymore either, which tries to run a `npm install`. Wondering where to look at...